# Condition in Event Structure Labview

Tags: structure, labview

[image]

Hi Guys,
I have in my labview project the needs to use the same prev/next buttons with different tab controls, so I tried to put the value change of those buttons in an event structure but I would to put in AND condition the availability of the current tab.

Any Idea??

Thank you very much.

Guido

Comment: There are some typos/grammar errors in your question. Would you tidy it up a little? To see if I understand, the 'next' and 'prev' buttons appear to be Boolean controls. They currently control cycling through the tabs of tab control A; and now you want them to also control cycling through tab control B? Also, what do you mean by "OR condition the availability of the current tab"?

Comment: Sorry for my grammar, what I meant with And condition is that, in the event structure I can set as condition all the options related to the object in the front panel, anyway I'd like to activate a certain state when a button "value change" AND a tab is "visible/active/enabled". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider using Dynamic Registering for Events: http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/lvhowto/dynamic_register_event/

You should create Dynamic event register and when tab control state is enabled/visible you will generate user event.

For example please refer to NI Example Finder and open "User Event Generation.vi"

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use property nodes for the tab controls, you can use the equality primitive to confirm whether the currently active tab is the one your event should handle. By adding more checks or processing, you can eliminate false positives.

#### Example

*Apologies for the bad wiring, the snippet tool mutated the block diagram.*

[image]